# Output correct IP

Tags: powershell, ip, output, customization, ping

Right now the below script imports info from a CSV file then outputs in a CSV file the computer name, expectedIP, Status, GoodIP, dnsName. This is all through custom PS object.

I am currently trying to get an output known as actual IP. I am not quite sure how to pull the IP via the ping function that pings the host name. For instance if the hostname that is being pinged check the IP and returns true or false. How could it output what the actual IP of the server is instead of outputting true or false?

Here is the script:

```
$compinfo = import-csv .\compinfo.csv

$lookupData = foreach ($comp in $cominfo) {
    $nslkup = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($comp.hname)
    $ping = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp.hname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if ($ping) {
        $status = "up"
    } else {
        $status = "down"
    }
    if ($nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString -eq $comp.ip) {
        $ipgood = $true
    } else {
        $ipgood = $false
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        computerName = $comp.hname
        expectedIp   = $comp.ip
        status       = $status
        goodIp       = $ipgood
        dnsName      = $nslkup.hostname
    }
}

$lookupData | Export-Csv .\lookups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am not sure how to identify `the` IP address. A host may have several IP addresses. On a network with access to the outside world, use the `nslookup hp.com` command and tell me which IP address is the one.

Comment: they are imported via a csv file which looks like this:
    hname,ip
    VIRTUALSERVER1,10.1.10.6
    DC1,10.1.10.7

Comment: Are you saying that the .csv file already has both the hostname and IP address? If you have the IP address, what are you looking for `Test-Connection` to provide?

Comment: `Test-Connection` returns a Win32_PingStatus object which contains `IPV4Address` and `IPV6Address` members. Is that what you are looking for? Use `Test-Connection -ComputerName VIRTUALSERVER | Get-Member` to see.

Comment: Alternatively you could use `[Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($comp.hname)` (or `Resolve-DnsName $comp.hname` if you're running Windows 8.1/Server 2012 or newer).

Comment: You already pull DNS info, why not just `ActualIp = $nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString -join ', '`

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone that commented on this. I figured it out. Here is the correct code for anyone else that has this issue in the future.

```
$compinfo = import-csv .\compinfo.csv

$lookupData = foreach($comp in $compinfo)
{
    $nslkup = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry($comp.hname)
    $ping = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp.hname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($ping)
    {
        $status = "up"
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "down"
    }
    if($nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString -eq $comp.ip)
    {
        $ipgood = $true
    }
    else
    {
        $ipgood = $nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        computerName = $comp.hname
        expectedIp = $comp.ip
        status = $status
        goodIp = $ipgood
        dnsName = $nslkup.hostname
    }
} 

$lookupData | export-csv .\lookups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Notice I replaced $False with $nslkup.AddressList.IPAddressToString

Comment: `AddressList` is a list. An array. `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostEntry('hp.com').AddressList.IPAddressToString`